# Clear cache or memory in Python

Tags: python, caching

I have a really large table need to calculate (10 billion + rows). It's too long to calculate all of them at one time. Therefore, I create a list of break points, and I calculate and store at the end of each step. However, each step costs longer time. I think the reason is the memory or cache, do you have any idea how to deal with in this situation or just how to clear cache or memory?

I reuse the variable for output in the loop, so the variable will not become bigger and bigger.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Where do you store them? In a file or database?

Comment: Cache is irrelevant, no software outside *maybe* the OS directly messes with that (cache is hardware-driven, not software).

Comment: How does the mentioned large table implemented? Is it a database table or a dictionary?

Comment: store into SQL server. @AlexHall

Comment: It's retrieved from SQL server, and transformed to pandas.DataFrame, And then calculated and stored into SQL server. @ImrePiller

Comment: Okay, Thank you.@Delioth

Comment: Could I just delete the variable to free the memory?

Answer (score 7):

I use to solve this issue using a line that reset the variable at the end of the process, cleaning the cache:

```
MyVariable = None
```

Comment: How is that different from `del MyVariable` in terms of cleaning the cache?